# Linux newbie trying to update KDE plasma from 5.20 to 5.27

Tags: linux, kde

I currently have kde plasma 5.20.5 running on Parrot OS 5.2(Ara)
I want to upgrade it to the latest 5.27 version, but dont know how to do it
If i need to get multiple updates thats ok, i just want to get to the latest version

I have tried updating it from 'discover', but its showing everything is upto date
I have also added the KDE neon repository, but it is downloading an older version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only do that by basically replacing all that your distro offers in KDE; I'd very strongly recommend against that:

Your distro's packages depend on exactly the versions of KDE and plasma that the distro ships. You cannot update plasma in isolation!

If you need a newer version than your distro ships, you will essentially have to wait until your distro updates – or use a different distro. I don't know Parrot OS, but it seems to be a conservative debian derivative (not debian, hence I removed the [debian](/questions/tagged/debian) tag); i.e., one of the worse ways to get bleeding edge software. Fedora 37, 38… and Debian Bookworm already ship 5.27.

Comment: So does this mean there is no way for me to do it, unless i get an actual debian OS like Fedora? I dont think parrot os will update it because Parrot OS 5.2 was released 2 months ago, and it shipped with 5.20 . Thanks for your help

Comment: Fedora is not a "debian OS": But yes, it means that on your current distro, the best way forward is to wait for an update. Wikipedia says Parrot OS is a "rolling release" distro, so it would suggest to me that they'd roll out updates as they get around to it. (Parrot, being based on debian, probably makes it easier for you to deal with debian than with fedora. As said, I have not used it myself, so I can't tell you anything about differences.)